# How to link a custom paper format to a pdf report in Odoo 8?

Tags: xml, report, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I want to print labels from odoo. For that I created a custom paper format and finding a way to link it to my label report. My label report is a pdf report. (When I create  the report I can view it in the default paper format.)

this is the code for custom paper format

```
<openerp>
<data>
    <record id="mymodule_label" model="report.paperformat">
        <field name="name">Item Label</field>
        <field name="default" eval="True"/>
        <field name="format">custom</field>
        <field name="page_height">50</field>
        <field name="page_width">100</field>
        <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
        <field name="margin_top">3</field>
        <field name="margin_bottom">3</field>
        <field name="margin_left">3</field>
        <field name="margin_right">3</field>
        <field name="header_line" eval="False"/>
        <field name="header_spacing">3</field>
        <field name="dpi">80</field>
    </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

I repeat my problem is how to link this paper format with my pdf report

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Custom paper formate for  Qweb report**

```
<report
    id="lukasz_orders_report_qweb"
    string="Drukuj Zgloszenie"
    model="lukasz.orders"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="your_module_name.lukasz_orders_report"
    file="your_module_name.lukasz_orders_report"
 />

<record id="paperformat_lowmargin" model="report.paperformat">
    <field name="name">European A4 low margin</field>
    <field name="default" eval="True" />
    <field name="format">A4</field>
    <field name="page_height">0</field>
    <field name="page_width">0</field>
    <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
    <field name="margin_top">4</field>
    <field name="margin_bottom">4</field>
    <field name="margin_left">4</field>
    <field name="margin_right">4</field>
    <field name="header_line" eval="False" />
    <field name="header_spacing">0</field>
    <field name="dpi">90</field>
</record>

<record id="your_module_name.lukasz_orders_report_qweb" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
    <field name="paperformat_id" ref="your_module_name.paperformat_lowmargin" />
</record>
```

Here, I added the custom paper format to the QWeb report.

I hope this is helpful for you ..:)

Comment: Great!! This is the exact piece of code I was looking for. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 3):

this's will work well :

```
<report
      id="lukasz_orders_report_qweb"
      string="Drukuj Zgloszenie"
      model="lukasz.orders"
      report_type="qweb-pdf"
      name="your_module_name.lukasz_orders_report"
      file="your_module_name.lukasz_orders_report"
      paperformat="your_module_name.paperformat_lowmargin"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also link the paper format from                                                                                          `settings-->Report-->Reports-->search your report name--> open that in form view--> click edit button select the paper format from selection`

Answer (score -1):

for odoo 13 it worked for me:

```
<record id="factura_formato_papel" model="report.paperformat">
    <field name="name">name paperformat</field>
    <field name="default" eval="True" />
    <field name="format">A4</field>
    <field name="page_height">0</field>
    <field name="page_width">0</field>
    <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
    <field name="margin_top">4</field>
    <field name="margin_bottom">4</field>
    <field name="margin_left">4</field>
    <field name="margin_right">4</field>
    <field name="header_line" eval="False" />
    <field name="header_spacing">0</field>
    <field name="dpi">90</field>
    <field name="report_ids" eval="[(4,ref('name_of_your_module.id_report'))]"/>
</record>
```